# Interpolate a scalar field over a 3D mesh refining the grid

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have function f=f(x,y,z) computed numerically over a grid of points of size MxNxP.

I need to interpolate that values over a finer grid of (obviously) different dimensions. Like I do with interp1 when I have only some values of a function over an interval and I want to interpolate it to find the values at more points.

I tried executing this code:

```
XX=linspace(0,45,50);
YY=linspace(0,0.5,50);
ZZ=linspace(0,0.5,50);

U_1 = interp3(X,Y,Z,f,XX,YY,ZZ,'linear')
```

where X Y Z are the vectors of points where I have the values of f. XX,YY,ZZ are the points where I want the solution.

I tried with griddata and also with interp3 but I got the following error message:

> Error using griddedInterpolant
>       The grid vectors do not define a grid of points that match the given values.
>       Error in interp3 (line 133)
>          F = griddedInterpolant({X, Y, Z}, V, method,extrap);

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors do not define a grid of points that match the given values.

Error in interp3 (line 133)
        F = griddedInterpolant({X, Y, Z}, V, method,extrap);

Comment: you need to use either vectors of mixed orientations or matrices generated by `meshgrid` for the function `interp3`. Refer to documentation and/or provide more data on the format of data for f, X, Y and Z

Comment: f is a function that represents the flow-velocity in a channel. The dimensions of the channel are 40x0.5x0.5 and I have the values of the function f in X, Y, Z. 
I tried to do [XX,YY,ZZ] = meshgrid(0:hx:45,0:hy:0.5,0:hz:0.5) but it doesn't work. The error is still the same

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an irregular gridded data set. In this case you need to use the [`griddata()`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) function to interpolate.

Take care that your defining point arrays X,Y,Z have equal dimensions. Also the interpolant point arrays XX,YY,ZZ have to have equal dimensions.
That means the following expression must be `true` (or `1`):

```
all(size(X)==size(Y)) && all(size(X)==size(Z)))
```

For the creation of your interpolants you may use meshgrid. It is wise to adapt the range of your interpolation grid to your real data range:

```
[XX,YY,ZZ]=meshgrid(linspace(min(X(:)),max(X(:)),50), ...
                    linspace(min(Y(:)),max(Y(:)),50), ...
                    linspace(min(Z(:)),max(Z(:)),50));
```

This will probably give the result you expect.

Comment: Using griddata the error that I get is the following:

Error using scatteredInterpolant
Data point coordinates have inconsistent dimension.

Error in griddata>useScatteredInterp (line 189)
    F = scatteredInterpolant(inargs{1}(:),inargs{2}(:),inargs{3}(:), ...

Error in griddata (line 126)
        vq = useScatteredInterp(inputargs, numarg, method, 'none');


PS:I used mesh grid to generate XX,YY,ZZ

Comment: What about X Y and Z?

Comment: They represent the centers of the cells of the original mesh where f is computed. They are 3 arrays of x, y and z positions. The space between the positions are not omogeneus. Obviously their dimensions are M, N and P.

Comment: Sorry Georg but X, Y, Z haven't the same dimensions, how can I manage the fact that they have different dimensions?

Comment: X,Y,Z are the points in space where your function f is defined. If they do not have the same dimensions they are not a list of points coordinates but something else. For each X there must be a corresponding Y and Z value. How should you calculate f(X,Y,Z) if this is not the case?

Comment: Substitute X Y and Z by [X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(X,Y,Z)

Comment: So X Y and Z must be 3 matrices of dimensions MxNxP, right?

Comment: They could be. But it would also be OK if the are all of dimension Nx1 defining N points in 3d-space.

Comment: I have to think about it, I will try and i will let you know... Thank you!

Comment: Noo bow Matlab doesn't complain but now my matrix is full of NaN :( :( I did also [X, Y, Z] = meshgrid(X,Y,Z)

Comment: You should check whether the values in X are between min(XX(:)) and max(XX(:)) and the same for Y and Z. If your data ranges do not match you will get NaNs. See my edited solution for how to do this. And PLEASE: Provide a simple test data set. Everything depends on YOUR data. I con only guess whats wrong if I do not see data.